Help Using Beta Function to Evaluate $I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1+x^3}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$
I am trying to understand the solution to this integral. I have highlighted the step that is confusing me in red.
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1+x^3}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx$$
$$\text{let}\; x^2=u$$
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{u}(1+u)^4}+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{2(1+u)^4}\,dx$$
$$\color{red}{=\frac{1}{2}\left (\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{2})+\beta(2,2)\right )}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left ( \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{7}{2})}{\Gamma(4)}+\frac{\Gamma^2(2)}{\Gamma(4)} \right )$$
$$=\frac{5\sqrt{\pi}}{24}\Gamma\left (\frac{5}{2}\right )+\frac{1}{12}=\frac{5\sqrt{\pi}}{16}\Gamma\left (\frac{3}{2}\right )+\frac{1}{12}$$
$$=\frac{1}{12}+\frac{5\sqrt{\pi}}{32}\Gamma\left (\frac{1}{2}\right )$$
$$I=\frac{5\pi}{32}+\frac{1}{12}$$
I understand the Gamma function but am only slightly familiar with the Beta function. I know that the comma separates the input for the Gamma function and I understand the simplification in all the steps afterwards. What I don't understand is how $\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{2})$ and $\beta(2,2)$ is derived from the integrals in the previous step.
I did some research and found that the Beta function can not only be represented with the Gamma function but also as: $\beta(z_1,z_2)=\int_0^1t^{z_1-1}(1-t)^{z_2-1}\,dt$
I am still struggling to see the connection between these and how the line in red is derived. I appreciate your help.

Are you sure this integral converges? For $x \geq 1$ $\frac{1+x^3}{(1+x^2)^2} \geq \frac{x^3}{(1+x^2)^2} \geq \frac{1}{x+3}$. And the integral of $\frac{1}{x+3}$ diverges.

I think you are correct @zetko. The integral is order $\frac1x$ and integral calculator suggests it is divergent

Yes, the integral diverges

Where is coming the fourth power from ?

Look at the different representations of the beta function, the one best suited to this is:
$$B(z_1,z_2)=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{z_1-1}}{(1+t)^{z_1+z_2}}dt$$
in your case:
$$-\frac12=z_1-1\Rightarrow z_1=\frac12$$
$$4=z_1+z_2\Rightarrow z_2=4-\frac12=\frac72$$
you may use the same technique for the second integral. Hope this helps :)

EDIT:
using the substitution you have used should yield:
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{1+u^{3/2}}{(1+u)^2}\frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}(1+u)^2}du+\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{2(1+u)^2}du$$
so you have made a mistake somewhere when carrying out the substitution. Note that whilst this first integral does converge the second integral does not, and so your integral is divergent.

$$I=\int\frac{1+x^3}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx=\int\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx+\int\frac{x^3}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx=I_1+I_2$$
For $I_1$, one integration by parts leads to
$$I_1=\int\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\tan
   ^{-1}(x)\right)$$
For $I_2$, let, as you did, $x=\sqrt u$
$$I_2=\int\frac{x^3}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx=\int\frac{u}{2 (u+1)^2}\,du$$
One integration by parts leads to
$$I_2=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{u+1}+\log(u+1)\right) $$
Back to $x$
$$I=I_1+I_2=\frac 12\left(\frac{x+1}{x^2+1}+\tan^{-1}(x)+\log(1+x^2)\right)$$
Using series
$$J=\int_0^t\frac{1+x^3}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi -2}{4}+\log(t)+\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{1}{3 t^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^4}\right)   $$ which is in a relative error of $0.10$% if $t>4$ and $0.01$% if $t>8$.
